# Why do objects in parent/child processes have identical addresses?

Tags: c++, c, process, semaphore

I have two questions about the following code:

**The Code**:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sem_t sem;
    int var = 0;

    /* create, initialize semaphore */
    if( sem_init(&sem,1,1) < 0)
    {
        perror("semaphore initilization");
        exit(0);
    }

    int pid = fork();
    static const size_t loopLen = 5;
    if (0 == pid)
    { /* child process */
        for (size_t i = 0; i < loopLen; ++i)
        {
            sem_wait(&sem);
            std::string str("Child");
            std::cout << str << " process: &var(" << (void*)(&var) << ") var(" << var++ << ") &sem(" << (void*)(&sem) << ")" << std::endl;
            sem_post(&sem);
        }
    }
    else
    { /* parent process */
        for (size_t i = 0; i < loopLen; ++i)
        {
            sem_wait(&sem);
            std::string str("Parent");
            std::cout << str << " process: &var(" << (void*)(&var) << ") var(" << var++ << ") &sem(" << (void*)(&sem) << ")" << std::endl;
            sem_post(&sem);
        }
    }
}
```

**The Output**:

```
Parent process: &var(0xffffcbdc) var(0) &sem(0xffffcbe0)
Child process: &var(0xffffcbdc) var(0) &sem(0xffffcbe0)
Parent process: &var(0xffffcbdc) var(1) &sem(0xffffcbe0)
Child process: &var(0xffffcbdc) var(1) &sem(0xffffcbe0)
Parent process: &var(0xffffcbdc) var(2) &sem(0xffffcbe0)
Child process: &var(0xffffcbdc) var(2) &sem(0xffffcbe0)
Parent process: &var(0xffffcbdc) var(3) &sem(0xffffcbe0)
Child process: &var(0xffffcbdc) var(3) &sem(0xffffcbe0)
Parent process: &var(0xffffcbdc) var(4) &sem(0xffffcbe0)
Child process: &var(0xffffcbdc) var(4) &sem(0xffffcbe0)
```

**Question**:

Why are the addresses of `var` and `sem` the same when printed from the parent and child processes? I know that child processes get *a copy* of the content of the parent's memory space, but I thought processes have separate and distinct address spaces, and thereby no variables would be at the same memory location - yet this output seems to indicate otherwise.

**Question**:

Is this code actually synchronizing the two processes? I am skeptical. Although I called `sem_init` with the `pshared` flag nonzero, it again seems to be that the child process should be getting *a copy* of the semaphore. I don't see a mechanism by which `sem` is "shared" between the parent and child process: the semaphore is not named, and I don't understand how else the semaphore gets shared between parent and child process. I suspect that each process is simply acquiring and releasing its own "copy" of the semaphore, but I'm uncertain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the addresses, it's because a child process starts out as an exact *duplicate* of the parent process. That exact duplication includes the (virtual) memory map. [Read the `fork` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) for more information.

Regarding the semaphore, if you [read the `sem_init` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) you will see that

> If `pshared` is nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between processes, and should be located in a region of shared memory

This placement in shared memory is up to you to handle though, it's not something that's done automatically for you.

Comment: "This placement in shared memory is up to you" - am I correct, then, that in my code sample, `sem` is not really shared between the parent and child process? The child process' `sem` is simply a copy - but a distinct object - of the parent process' `sem` ?

Comment: @StoneThrow That's true. I suggest you [read about POSIX shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html).

Answer (score 4):

Linux uses the "[copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)" idiom, which means that after you call `fork()`, the parent's memory is not immediately copied (as a separate copy) for the child. The copy will only occur when the child process will attempt to write any data into the memory.

It is also important to understand the difference between the "real" memory address (i.e. the address in the physical memory) and the mapped address, which is an address in the memory space of your application. Two pointers in two applications might have the same value (virtual address), but that does not mean they really point to the same physical location: [Memory mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Comment: Is it really because of copy on write? I mean, even if the memory were copied immediately, would that affect the addresses in any way?

Comment: @user2079303, I should probably clarify that. If we talk about physical addresses, yes. If we talk about mapped addresses, probably not.

Comment: @user2079303: it is because the two processes have distinct virtual address spaces. Two equal addresses in two different processes can map to different physical memory.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Hence my suspicion that copy on write wouldn't have an effect on the virtual addresses, that OP prints.

Comment: An application program never gets to see physical addresses.

Comment: @user2079303: COW is just an optimization technique that wouldn't affect the virtual addresses. The idea of COW is to maintain the mapping to the same physical addresses until one of the processes attempts to write at the same location.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to SingerOfTheFall's answer, I would like to add that `fork(2)` makes an exact copy of the parent process - same memory maps, same signal masks, same file descriptor table - so you actually get a true copy of your process.

The processes do have distinct addresses spaces, but in order to understand why modifying one of the processes doesn't affect the other, you should bear in mind the difference between virtual and physical addresses and that all processses (even the kernel on amd64 anyways) executes in virtual address space.

Long story - short, there are correspondances tables (called page tables) in the CPU, and whenever you try to access a given address, the CPU looks up the real physical address of the offending address. The kernel populates the page tables for every process and it gives the same addresses to everyone (if ASLR is not enabled).

I can't say for sure why the semaphore is shared between the parent and the child, but if your initiliasiation is correct, it shouldn't be accessible from the outside world.

Cf.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table